# jpeg decoding when data is given in array

Tags: java, image

i am using LibJpeg library for decoding jpeg image ( given in form of byte array ) into rgb color map .
 but it come different from my sample output i want to check by java programme .
 how to do this in by java programme ?
 what is use of APPn in header ?
 how to decode jpeg image into rgb pixel .

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried till now and what is not working as per your expectations? thanks.

Comment: i have libjpeg library and getting image in bmp format from raw data of jpeg but sample output is taken from blackberry that is in rgb pixel . when i read pixel of my libjpeg output(output.bmp) value by rgb() in java it give me different pixel value from that of sample output taken from blackberry . is there any reason for this?

Comment: Please provide som code.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use [`ImageIO.read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) together with [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to read the byte array into an image then no extra library is needed (pure java solution):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```