# How to convert workspace object containing jpeg file data to image array

Tags: matlab, jpeg

I have some MATLAB data objects in my workspace that are produced by third-party tools which extract jpeg images from other third-party mixed-data files.  I know I can convert the jpeg data (long vector of UINT8 values) to a MATLAB X-by-Y-by-3 image array by writing to a binary file and then reading that file back in using `imread` .  What I'm looking for is a way to perform the jpeg conversion  on the workspace object directly so that I don't have to waste time doing a write & read.
 So far as I can tell,   `fopen` and `imread` don't allow redirects to StandardIn .
I'm currently limited to MATLAB 2015, no Toolboxes such as ImageProcessing available.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660226/1377097) does it with the help of Java, and apparently inspired [this submission](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53716-decodejpeg) to File Exchange. I haven't used either, but they may be of some help.

Comment: Decoding a jpg is quite complex. [Here is some information about it](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-huffman-coding.html). maybe that helps.

Comment: @PatrickHappel  I actually wrote a jpg decoder long ago (and lost it of course!).  That's why I was hoping there was a way to grab the guts of imread.

Comment: @beaker thanks!  I  added a comment at your linked answer containing the FEX link;  have now voted to close my own question here as a dupe.