# JCodec's JpegDecoder usage

Tags: java, jpeg, decode

I need to decode `jpeg` images using pure java libraries and came across `JCodec`, that seems to offer such a feature.

There is a JpegDecoder class, with a `public Picture decodeFrame(ByteBuffer data, int[][] data2)` method. The thing is that I cannot understand what the arguments are, and their name (`data` and `data2`) is not meaningful...

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score -1):

The first parameter is a bytebuffer object the second is an two-dimensional int array. Maybe check out this answer...

[jpeg decoding when data is given in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413885/jpeg-decoding-when-data-is-given-in-array)

This is the basic idea to get an image as data.

```
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);
 WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
 DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
```

Comment: This was not helpful: you did not help the understanding of the usage of the library in any way. You simply stated obvious information about the parameters and presented an unrelated example.